# Adding a Style to a Slider Control in Mathematica's Manipulate function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to add a font style for the variable  z in my Slider control below. In this toy manipulate example when the user changers the SetterBar or Slider values, the y slider is reset to y=0.1. Of course I can wrap the z Slider control with Row[{Style["Z",Bold], {z, Slider ....}], but then I need to somehow suppress the appearance of z. Thanks in advance for any help.

Brian

```
Manipulate[
Module[{}, {x, y, z}], {x, 
SetterBar[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = 0.1) &], {"A", "B", "C"}] &}, {z, 
Slider[Dynamic[z, (z = #; y = 0.1) &], {.1, 10}, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"] &},
{{y, 0.1, Style["Y", 14]}, 0.1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
Initialization :> ({x, z} = {"B", 1})]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do what I think you're asking for is with the `{{u, uinit, ulbl}, ...}` control spec form that you've already used in the spec form for `y`. For example:

```js
Manipulate[
 Module[{}, {x, y, z}],
 {x, SetterBar[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = 0.1) &], {"A", "B", "C"}] &},
 {{z, .1, Style["Z", Darker@Green, Bold, 16, FontFamily -> Times]}, 
  Slider[Dynamic[z, (z = #; y = 0.1) &], {.1, 10}, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"] &},
 {{y, 0.1, Style["Y", 14]}, 0.1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> ({x, z} = {"B", 1})]
```

This doesn't require much restructuring of your expression, if you'd like to avoid that...